# Spring mvc servlet url does not map correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, url, servlets

When I go to the first url, it calls my home() method in the controller but when I go to the second url it does not call my homeTest() method. Why is that?

I get 404 error.

```
http://localhost:9083/MYAPP/foo       ------ first url
http://localhost:9083/MYAPP/foo/bar  ------ second url
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/foo/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Model model){
    return "home";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/foo/bar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homeTest(Model model){
    return "home";
}
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @JohnDonn I get SRVE0295E:Error reported: 404

Comment: You can try to debug Spring's DispatcherServlet (or change your log levels accordingly). At some point you should see, if I recall correctly, a list of all URL paths mapped. This might help you to understand what is going on.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have an analogous issue, and have logging turned up. It helps, but I'm still not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure your [`RequestMappingHandlerMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html).

The official documentation goes into detail about [handler mappings](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping) and some of their properties. The relevant one here is [`alwaysUseFullPath`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerMapping.html#setAlwaysUseFullPath-boolean-):

> - **`alwaysUseFullPath`** If `true`, Spring uses the full path within the current Servlet context to find an appropriate handler. If `false`
>     (the default), the path within the current Servlet mapping is used.
>     For example, if a Servlet is mapped using `/testing/*` and the
>     `alwaysUseFullPath` property is set to true, `/testing/viewPage.html`
>     is used, whereas if the property is set to false, `/viewPage.html` is
>     used

In short, when trying to find a mapping for `/foo/bar`, it removes the part that was matched by the Servlet environment, the `/foo`, and only uses the `/bar` to find a handler. You have no handler mapped to `/bar`.

By setting the property above to `true`, it will use the full path.

You can configure this in a `@Configuration` annotated [`WebMvcConfigurationSupport`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html) subclass, by overriding [`requestMappingHandlerMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html#requestMappingHandlerMapping--)

```
@Override
public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
    RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
    handlerMapping.setAlwaysUseFullPath(true);
    return handlerMapping;
}
```

Or whatever mechanism is appropriate for your configuration (there's an XML equivalent for example).

---

There's a special case for the exact match of `/foo`. It's not particularly relevant here.

Answer (score -1):

Just change:

```
<url-pattern>/foo/*</url-pattern>
```

To

```
<url-pattern>/foo/**</url-pattern>
```

Comment: I still get 404 with this change

Comment: @Nero keep your controller as it is and only update the servlet mapping. Check the updated answer.

Comment: I am not allowed to change the url-pattern, it has to stay /foo/*, so that the urls with "/foo/" are only handled by spring servlet

Comment: @Nero Then do this `/foo/**` instead of `/foo/*`. check the updated answer.

Comment: How do you think a Servlet container interprets `**`? Why do you think so?

Comment: @Nero did you check with `/foo/**` ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You should check http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html amd read this before downvoting.

Comment: You just linked a Spring class. What does that have to do with a Servlet container url pattern? It's the [servlet specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-oth-JSpec/) you should be linking to, but I see nothing there that would explain why `**` would do anything valid.

Comment: Please improve your answer with an explanation as to what that change will achieve.